# Show tabular output in richtextbox

Tags: winforms, powershell, richtextbox, powershell-studio

Just installed the PowerShell Studio and I'm trying to view the results of some VMware commands in a richtextbox.

When I run the `get-vm`, for example, it shows the data fine (I changed the font to Lucida Console- and it looks ok), regular `get-vm` results in the richtext box:

```
Name : xxx
Cluster : xxx
ESX Host : esx6
Datastore : xxx
MemoryGB : 8
NumCpu : 2
ProvisionedSpace(GB) : 282
UsedSpace(GB) : 281
OS : Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)
```

But when I try to run `(get-vm).Guest.Disks` the data not shown good in the richtextbox, it looks like this:

```
Capacity:192515403776,
FreeSpace:43895230464,
Path:E:\

Capacity:75053920256,
FreeSpace:12630409216,
Path:C:\
```

when run it in regular powershell console it look like it should:

```
Volume Capacity(GB) FreeSpace(GB) % FreeSpace
------ ------------ ------------- -----------
E:\    120          13            11
C:\    120          15            12
```

The command line in PowerShell is:

```
((Get-VM $vm).Guest.disks) | Format-Table @{N="Volume";E={$_.Path}},
    @{N="Capacity(GB)";E={[System.Math]::Round($_.CapacityGB)};a="left"},
    @{N="FreeSpace(GB)";E={[System.Math]::Round($_.FreeSpaceGB)};a="left"},
    @{N="% FreeSpace";E={[math]::Round((100 * ($_.FreeSpacegb / $_.Capacitygb)),0)};a="left"} -auto |
  Out-String
```

the command line in the richtextbox is:

```
$richtextbox1.AppendText((Get-VM $text).Guest.disks) |
  Format-Table @{N="Volume";E={$_.Path}},
    @{N="Capacity(GB)";E={[System.Math]::Round($_.CapacityGB)};a="left"},
    @{N="FreeSpace(GB)";E={[System.Math]::Round($_.FreeSpaceGB)};a="left"},
    @{N="% FreeSpace";E={[math]::Round((100 * ($_.FreeSpacegb / $_.Capacitygb)),0)};a="left"} -auto |
 Out-String
```

How can I get the results like it looks in the PowerShell console wheter is with richtextbox or any other control?

Comment: Why not use ListView or ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your richtextbox gives you the results in list format. Pipe your results into the [`Format-Table`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) cmdlet before piping it into `Out-String` to enforce table format:

```
... | Format-Table | Out-String
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the following fixed size fonts to display the output:
Consolas
Courier New
Lucida Console

Comment: Please expand on your answer. It's very short.